# Retrieve the songs in a shared iTunes library via terminal?

Tags: shell, itunes

I am trying to write a script that will run in terminal on OSX, and will basically read all the shared library that my iTunes can find, and retrieve data like the song name, artist and so on.

Is there a way to do this in Terminal? So far I had no luck in finding any kind of interface that would allow terminal to talk with iTunes, and retrieve the shared library data.

I need to find out if certain artist or songs are on our network, and going every day, one shared library at time is incredibly time consuming.  I want to script it so every day it will scan all the shared library on our network, and find what I need.

Thanks

Comment: The last time I looked (a very long time ago), the iTunes library file on OS X was a `.plist`, which is readable as text, no?  So you could write some Python to read it.  In fact, it looks as though someone has already written a [library](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/plistlib.html) just for you ...

Comment: yeah, the library itself is a plist, but the shared ones are not saved locally; so unless there is a way to go trough iTunes (Applescript?), I don't see how you can retrieve info from shared libraries